# Modify Optaplanner Vehicle Routing Problem vehicleRoutingScoreRules.drl to erase Hard constraint

Tags: optaplanner, self-modifying

I want to modify the optaplanner example vehicle routing problem to erase Hard contraint and convert it to vrp no cvrp. I try to comment Hard contraints at `vehicleRoutingScoreRule.drl`, but it does not change anything.

```
//############################################################################
// Hard constraints
// ############################################################################

/*rule "vehicleCapacity"
when
    $vehicle : Vehicle($capacity : capacity)
    accumulate(
        Customer(
            vehicle == $vehicle,
            $demand : demand);
        $demandTotal : sum($demand);
        $demandTotal > $capacity
    )
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $capacity - $demandTotal);
end
*/
```

Comment: That should work. Try writing in some garbage in that drl file and confirm it crashes to prove that what you run is what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, was my fault,  i haven't deleted optaplanner-examples.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Done!, it was that in the classpath i didn't remove the optaplanner-examples.jar.
Thanks,